# How to send text to content page as query string from Master Page

Tags: asp.net

I have a search textbox that I tried wrapping in a form element:

```
<form id="searchForm" method="GET" action="Search.aspx">
    <input name="term" type="text" id="searchTerm" class="nav-search" size="30" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" style="display:none;"/>
</form>
```

I can't get it to redirect to the content page (Search.aspx) with the query string (term) from the Master Page.

I tried wrapping it in an ASP:Panel and using the DefaultButton Property but that wouldn't call the Click event in code behind.

I'm perplexed as I've searched for a solution for hours and this seems like a such common task. Thanks.

Comment: You don't pass values from Master page to a content page through query string. Actually Masterpage is a special type of page that you can't call like other .aspx pages. It's just a template for a content page. If you need to use a value in master page in your content page just use this.Master object. This will have all public properties and methods of your master page

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I re-direct to the search page to display results from a search textbox (located on the master page) from any page?

Comment: Use Response.Redirect. E.g. use it like this Response.Redirect("~/Search.aspx")

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
<input name="term" type="text" id="searchTerm" runat="server" class="nav-search" size="30" />

<asp:Button ID="searchsubmit" OnClick="searchsubmit_Click" runat="server" Text="Search" />
```

in Site.Master.cs add something like this

```
protected void searchsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/search.apsx?content=" + searchTerm.text);
        }
```

This will allow to search with button click, if you want to  hide it, add also panel around first code, saying that this is a button to automatically press when enter is pressed Something like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="UserPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="searchsubmit">
```

Comment: I have exactly this and when I put text in the textbox and hit enter, the page appears to do a postback and doesn't redirect at all.

Comment: I have exactly the same on my website and it works ok. Try adding try catch around Response redirect code. Next check in debug mode if it enters searchsubmit_Click method when you press enter. Second thing to check if you make submit button visible, if it works when you click on it.